# Is it possible to set a property on QTreeView item

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qobject, qtstylesheets, qabstractitemmodel

QSS allows styling `QTreeView` and has a set of predefined child elements, e.g. `QTreeView::item`.
I would like to add finer model-driven granularity to it using property selector (`QTreeView::item[myproperty=myvalue]`). This way I could have data-driven display and at the same time it would be customizible via QSS.

Is there a way I could access the item of `QTreeView` (note, not the `QTreeWidget`), so that I could set a property on it based on the data returned from the model?

Are there any other ways of driving which style to apply to a given item from the model (other than returning font, color etc)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use user roles for this.  When you add the data to the model as DisplayRole, you can also add information as UserRole or define your own role.  When it comes to display decoration, get data based on the user role, not the DisplayRole.

Comment: My question was rather what to do next: once the `model().data(Qt::UserRole)` returned "myvalue", how do I assign it to the property of a tree view item in the view or the delegate code.

Comment: Hi, Same problem for me..  Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No - ended up doing the model-driven styling outside QSS